# ACTUALIZAR BASE DE DATOS DESDE QT CREATOR

Tags: c++, base-de-datos, qt-creator

hice esta parte de codigo para actualizar un valor de la base de datos, pero quisiera que el id lo pueda recibir desde el qstring declarado antes, ya funciona pero solo si pongo manualmente el valor del id en el prepare, como se puede hacer? gracias.

```
QString cantidad= ui->line_cantidad->text();
QString id= ui->line_id->text();

if(db.open()){
    QSqlQuery qry;
    
    //aqui en lugar de 2 pasaria la variable id, como se debe declarar?
    qry.prepare("UPDATE db SET cantidad=:cantidad_ WHERE id=2");
    qry.bindValue(":cantidad_",cantidad);

    if(qry.exec()){
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Finalizado","Cantidad enviada");
        close();
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(this,"No actualizado","No se pudo enviar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El argumento del método usa `const QString`:

```
bool QSqlQuery::prepare(const QString &query)
```

Así que podrías concatenar `id`, que ya es `QString`
Hay varias formas:

Usando `arg`:

```
qry.prepare("UPDATE db SET cantidad=:cantidad_ WHERE id=%1").arg(id);
```

Usando el operador +:

```
qry.prepare("UPDATE db SET cantidad=:cantidad_ WHERE id=" + id + """);
```